# Extract prefix of a path of given length

Tags: java

Given an absolute path, how to extract the beginning part of this path of some given length? Effectively, the same value that I would get if I invoked `getParent()` the needed number of times.

I also need this to be filesystem-independent.

I see that there is `Path.subpath`, but it does not seem to be what I want: `Path.of("/","a","b","c").subpath(0,2)` gives `a/b`, but I need `/a/b`. Yes, I can get the root and then create a new path from the results of `subpath()` and the root, but then is it going to be system-independent?

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried considering Apache Commons FilenameUtils?

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two simple ways to make it platform independent are the ways you suggest: Path with getParent, or Path getRoot+subpath. These should give identical results:

```
public static Path subpath1(Path p, int parts) {
    if (parts < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("parts must be positive");
    // Go up from path appropriate number of times:
    return Stream.iterate(p, Path::getParent)
                 .skip(Math.max(0, p.getNameCount() - parts))
                 .findFirst().get();
}
public static Path subpath2(Path p, int parts) {
    if (parts < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("parts must be positive");
    // Resolve the subpath from the root
    Path sub = p.subpath(0, parts);
    Path root = p.getRoot();
    return root != null ? root.resolve(sub) : sub;
}
```

However note that system-independence rather depends on your input data because `Path.of("/","a","b","c")` on Windows means UNC pathname `\\a\b\c` and NOT a path `\a\b\c` which starts from whatever your current drive happens to be. So if you use `Path.of("/","a","b","c")` in all platforms you'll see different results if run on Windows vs Linux.

To be consistent, specify Windows and Linux paths using "/a/b/c" form not  "/","a","b","c". Here are some tests which show these differences:

```
private static void check(Path expected, Path input, int parts) {
    assertEquals(expected, subpath1(input, parts));
    assertEquals(expected, subpath2(input, parts));
}
@EnabledOnOs(OS.WINDOWS)
@Test void testSubpathsWindows() {
    check(Path.of("C:/a/b"), Path.of("C:\\", "a", "b", "c", "d"), 2);
    check(Path.of("C:\\a"),  Path.of("C:\\", "a", "b", "c", "d"), 1);

    // UNC paths - note that Path.of("/", "a", "b", ... ) is UNC \\a\b
    check(Path.of("\\\\a\\b\\c"), Path.of("/", "a", "b", "c", "d"), 1);
    check(Path.of("\\\\a\\b\\c"), Path.of("\\\\a\\b\\c\\d"), 1);
}

@EnabledOnOs(OS.LINUX)
@Test void testSubpathsLinux() {
    check(Path.of("/", "a", "b"),  Path.of("/", "a", "b", "c", "d"), 2);
    check(Path.of("/a/b/c"),       Path.of("/", "a", "b", "c", "d"), 3);
    check(Path.of("a/b/c"),        Path.of("a", "b", "c", "d"), 3);
}
@Test void testSubpathsAllOS() {
    check(Path.of("/a/b"),  Path.of("/a/b/c/d"), 2);
    check(Path.of("/a/b/c"),       Path.of("/a/b/c/d/e"), 3);
    check(Path.of("a/b/c"),        Path.of("a/b/c/d"), 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you need but is does parse the supplied path string and return the number of segments desired. Read the comments in code:

```
/**
 * Returns the supplied path string at the desired path depth, for example:<pre>
 * 
 * If a path string consisted of: 
 * 
 *   "C:/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k"  OR  "C:\\a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i\\j\\k";
 * 
 * And we want the path from a depth of 6 then what is returned is:
 * 
 *     1  2 3 4 5 6
 *    "C:\a\b\c\d\e" 
 * 
 * If a path string consisted of: 
 * 
 *   "/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k"  OR  "\\a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i\\j\\k";
 * 
 * And we want the path from a depth of 6 then what is returned is:
 * 
 *      1 2 3 4 5 6
 *    "\a\b\c\d\e\f"  
 * 
 * Note that the File System Separator is used on the returned String. This 
 * can be changed in code by replaceing all instances of `File.Separator` 
 * with whatever string character you want.</pre>
 * 
 * @param absolutePath (String) The path string to acquire the path depth 
 * from.<br>
 * 
 * @param desiredDepth (int) The desired path depth to retrieve. If a path 
 * depth is provided that exceeds the number of directories within the 
 * supplied path string then the depth value will be modified to the MAX 
 * depth of that supplied path string. If a depth of 0 is provided, then
 * a Null String ("") is returned.<br>
 * 
 * @return (String) The Path string at the specified depth.
 */
public String getPathFromDepth(String absolutePath, int desiredDepth) {
    // Convert separators in supplied path string to forward slash (/)
    if (absolutePath.contains("\\")) {
        absolutePath = absolutePath.replace("\\", "/");
    }
    
    // Determine if the path string starts with a separator.
    boolean separatorStart = false;
    if (absolutePath.startsWith("/")) {
        separatorStart = true;                    // Flag the fact
        absolutePath = absolutePath.substring(1); // Remove the starting seperator
    }
    
    // Split the supplied (and modified) path string into an array:
    String[] pathParts = absolutePath.split("/");
    
    // See if the supplied depth goes beyond limits...
    if (desiredDepth > pathParts.length) {
        // It does, so make it to Max Limit.
        desiredDepth = pathParts.length;
    }
    
    // Prepare to build the new Path.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(""); 
    // Iterate through the created array one element at a time:
    for (int i = 0; i < desiredDepth; i++) {
        /* If the StringBuilder object contains something 
           then append a System File Separator character. */
        if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
            sb.append(File.separator);
        }
        /* If the supplied path started with a Seperator then 
           make sure the returned path does too. Append a File
           Sperator character to the build.            */
        if (separatorStart) {
            sb.append(File.separator);
            separatorStart = false; // Remove the flag so this doesn't get applied again.
        }
        // Append the current path segment from the String[] Array:
        sb.append(pathParts[i]);
    }
    
    // Return the Build Path String:
    return sb.toString();
}
```